# Trouble migrating custom post types from non-wordpress cms

Tags: query, mysql, import

I am working on migrating over some custom post types from a non-wordpress cms that we will call "shows." I am using a script in functions.php to try and accomplish this, but I am having trouble. I know the database exists and is valid, but I am unable to query the row properly. Instead of actual values, I am simply getting the value `1`. I Probably do not correctly understand a function somewhere in my code, but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
function import_shows() {
  $conn = mysqli_connect(constant("DB_HOST"), constant("DB_USER"), constant("DB_PASSWORD"), "THE_DB");

  if (!$conn) {
    error_log("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error(), 0);
    return;
  } 

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM shows";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $res = print_r($row, true);
          error_log($res, 0);

          error_log($row["id_show"]);
          $test++;
      } 
  }

  mysqli_close($conn);
  return;
}
```

When I go to check the error log after this has run, the first print is always `1` and the second print is always empty. Any ideas?

Comment: hmmm this is all generic PHP, I'm not sure this stack is the best place to ask, maybe stackoverflow? Have you tried using the `wpdb` class?

Comment: You are right, which is why this is so frustrating. I will look into it, my understanding was that it could only work with the wordpress db, but I just saw on the documentation that it can be reinstantiated to other dbs.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with a solution according to advice from the comments. Working code:

```
function import_shows() {
  $olddb = new wpdb(constant("DB_USER"),constant("DB_PASSWORD"),"THE_DB",constant("DB_HOST"));

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM shows";
  $rows = $olddb->get_results($sql);

  foreach($rows as $obj) {
    error_log($obj->name);
  }

  return;
}
```